# Passing a member function via std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

I want to check if a data field is valid (valid means being not null and not filled with the default value)

Basically

```
return (!connector->IsNull(field_id) and connector->Get<type>Default(field_id, default_value))
```

But "type" can be one of many types (string, int64, etc...) so there are 5-6 different functions. I made a helper function for it and I'm trying to pass in the relevant GetDefault...

```
template<typename T> bool IsValidField(std::unique_ptr<Connector>& connector, const std::function<T(int, T)> &GetDefault, int field_id, T default_value){
  return (!connector->IsNull(field_id) && connection->GetDefault(field_id, default_value) != default_value);
}
```

And I'm calling the helper function with....

```
IsValidField(connector, connector->GetStringWithDefault,20,"")
```

I get the error "error: reference to non-static member function must be called
" because GetStringWithDefault isnt a static function, how do I fix this?

Alternately, is there a way of making it slightly less awkward?

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions, one is using [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and the other is using [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn).

---

For the solution using [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) it could look something like

```
template<typename T, typename F>
bool IsValidField(std::unique_ptr<Connector>& connector, F GetDefault,
                  int field_id, T default_value)
{
    return (!connector->IsNull(field_id) &&
            GetDefault(field_id, default_value) != default_value);
}
```

Then call it like

```
IsValidField(

IsValidField(connector,
             std::bind(&ClassForConnector::GetStringWithDefault, _1, _2),
             20,"");
```

---

For the [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) solution, maybe something like

```
template<typename T, typename F>
bool IsValidField(std::unique_ptr<Connector>& connector, F GetDefault,
                  int field_id, T default_value)
{
    return (!connector->IsNull(field_id) &&
            GetDefault(connector, field_id, default_value) != default_value);
}
```

And call it like

```
IsValidField(connector,
             std::mem_fn(&ClassForConnector::GetStringWithDefault),
             20,"");
```

Comment: Is it possible to delete the "connector" argument somehow?

Comment: @Narabhut Not unless you remove the `connector->IsNull(field_id)` check.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the most neat, but the most trivial solution seems to be to wrap everything into lambda:

`IsValidField(connector, [connector]() -> T {return connector->GetStringWithDefault(20, "")})`

But then you need to adjust the `IsValidField` signature accordingly.

Comment: For this, I wouldn't even need the function right? I guess I'm ok with making 4-5 of these if they're one liners like this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things going on here.  Do one thing at a time.

Clean up how to call the `GetStringWithDefault`, so you can get something based off its type without knowing the name of the function, as follows:

```
namespace impl {
  template<class T, T Connector::*Method(int, T const&)>
  struct GetWithDefault {
    T operator()(Connector const& connector, int id, T const& default) const {
      return (connector.*Method)(id, default);
  };
}

template<class T>
struct GetWithDefault;

template<>struct GetWithDefault<std::string>:
  impl::GetWithDefault<std::string, &Connector::GetStringWithDefault>
{};
```

repeat for each supported type.  Now, `GetWithDefault<Bob>{}(*connector, id, default_bob)` does what you want.

Now the null version:

```
template<class T>
bool IsValidField(Connector const& connector, int id, T const& default_value) {
    return !connector.IsNull(id) && (GetWithDefault<T>{}(connector, id, default_value)!=default_value);
  }
};
```

This moves the association between `T` and the gettor into a  helper type `GetWithDefault`, where we implement it via explicit specialization (sort of like a traits class).